# I cant locate .htaccess in joomla so i can't rewrite/ add details

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I have built a website in joomla 3. However it can't play my mp3 videos previews and yet they can play on safari. In firefox i can only see a black window. Again they seem to take a while to load. See the link click on the previews.

http://www.downloadmathvideos.com/index.php/videos/arithmetics

I have read several articles and links and they all say add/ change the mime type. The details below is what i would like to add to the htaccess.

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

However at the back end i cant locate .htaccess. I can only see htaccess.txt is it one and the same? Do i rename it to .htaccess? if i do where/ after which line do i add the details above.

I have tried puting the details above in the htaccess.txt but there is no change.

Answer (score 3):

you download htaccess.txt, then rename from your pc, then upload it.But .htaccess must have write permission 
thanks

Comment: Thanks Bipul khan. Let me try that.

Comment: I finally managed to change to .htaccess but my mac could not allow that. I had to do it on a pc, then i had to click on show hidden files. I have tried putting the files above on different places in the htaccess but i have not succeeded. Where exactly do i put these files?
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm